# Why is this javascript method firing even when I'm not calling it?

Tags: javascript

Just trying to get my head around Javascript a very strange thing has happened. The method `getChapters()` is firing even though I haven't explicitly called it...Any ideas? (I'm getting the alert box for get chapters).

```
videoChapters = function () {
};

videoChapters.prototype.config = {
    jsonProvider : '_Chapters.aspx'
};

videoChapters.prototype.init = function () {
    //get chapters
};

videoChapters.prototype.getChapters = new function () {
    alert('getting chapters');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    videoChapters = new videoChapters();
    videoChapters.init();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
videoChapters.prototype.getChapters = new function () {
```

...should probably not contain the word 'new'. When Javascript attempts to evaluate the expression, it passes the result of your function to the 'new' operator.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `new` keyword:

```
videoChapters.prototype.getChapters = function () {
    alert('getting chapters');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
....prototype.getChapters = new function () {
                            ^-------- See the new keyword here?
```

Remove the `new` keyword and everything will work as expected, using `new` will invoke the function as an constructor and return a new instance of it, in this case a new instance of an anonymous function.